# correct z-index of the div element

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="caption_center">
    <h1 class="caption_header font-alpha">Robíme Váš svet pohodlnejší</h1>
    <p class="caption_regular font-alpha">Dovolte nám presvedčiť Vás o tom</p>
    <div class="caption_center_Background"></div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.caption_center {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    left: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    width: 60%;
    /*background: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.55);*/
    padding-top:1em;
}

.caption_center_Background {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:0;
}

.caption_header  {
    z-index:999;
}

.caption_regular {
    z-index:998;
}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve (in the end) is that this black box will have opacity of 0.5 and the text will be in front of this black box. This way, no matter what the background on my image is, user will still be able to see the text (that's why the semi-transparent black box).

Nonetheless, even though I have specified my z-index, I still cannot force the text to go in front of the black div box. I have also tried to make the box as first element (meaning it was before `h1` and `p` elements), but with no change.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. I was trying to mimic [the following **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kdzD9/4/).

Comment: Yes, it is. It should be interiting the color from the `.caption_center`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no problems with the `z-index` but you need to specify the `position` for it to work. Setting a value for `position` attribute is critical for the working because `z-index` has no effect on elements whose `position` is `static` (which is the default value for `position` attribute).

From [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/): (emphasis is mine)

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically closer to you. ***z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than static (the default)***.

```css
.caption_center {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  width: 60%;
  /*background: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.55);*/
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.caption_center_Background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 0;
}
.caption_header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.caption_regular {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 998;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption_center">
  <h1 class="caption_header font-alpha">Robíme Váš svet pohodlnejší</h1>
  <p class="caption_regular font-alpha">Dovolte nám presvedčiť Vás o tom</p>
  <div class="caption_center_Background"></div>
</div>
```

---

Another option would be to just set a negative `z-index` on `.caption_center_Background`. This way there would be no need to position (or) set high `z-index` to the other two elements that have the text.

```css
.caption_center {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  width: 60%;
  /*background: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.55);*/
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.caption_center_Background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption_center">
  <h1 class="caption_header font-alpha">Robíme Váš svet pohodlnejší</h1>
  <p class="caption_regular font-alpha">Dovolte nám presvedčiť Vás o tom</p>
  <div class="caption_center_Background"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Didn't know that the position was so crucial in here

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put your text inside this background div.

This is an updated snippet:

```css
.caption_center {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  width: 60%;
  /*background: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.55);*/
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.caption_center_Background {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 0;
}
/*.caption_header {
  z-index: 999;
}
.caption_regular {
  z-index: 998;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="caption_center">
  <div class="caption_center_Background">
    <h1 class="caption_header font-alpha">Robíme Váš svet pohodlnejší</h1>
    <p class="caption_regular font-alpha">Dovolte nám presvedčiť Vás o tom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this way you won't have any `position` or `z-index` problems, and don't forget to give the background div, the needed style `opacity : 0.5;`.

This should do the trick.

Comment: Nice option but note that adding `opacity: 0.5` to a parent will affect the opacity of the child also. (That is, if you change the text color to red or green etc then the display color won't be as expected).

Comment: Yes @Harry, well pointed out, I just used this option as the text is white, but there's no doubt that the option of fixing positions is the best clue here.

Comment: No, actually as I said it's well pointed out. It's a good tip indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...

```css
.caption_header  {
    position: relative;
    z-index:999;
}

.caption_regular {
    position: relative;
    z-index:998;
}
```